# Thunderbird (52.7.0) message filter based on whether Reply-to address is in address book

Tags: email, thunderbird

Is there a way to create a filter based on whether a Reply-to address is in my address book? I managed to add the Reply-to option to the drop-down of things to filter by. But the drop-down to set the conditions for filtering does not offer the "is in my address book" and "isn't in my address book" options as it does for when you filter by "From, To, CC or BCC." Any ideas on how to add that option for the "Reply-to"?